# How to efficiently write hundred of "if then else"

Tags: java, android

I have this function

```
private static string countryToLanguage(String countryCode){

  if (countryCode.equal("AD")) {return "ca"}
  else if (countryCode.equal("AE")) {return "ar"}
  else if (countryCode.equal("AG")) {return "en"}
  ...

}
```

Is their any more efficient way to do this? As it's a static function i can't use any kind of global variable (like hashmap)

Comment: Why do you think a static function can't use a "global" variable?

Comment: Why you cannot use a hashmap? You can have an static hashMap

Comment: This is what dictionaries were made for

Comment: While I am sure it will have less performance than a static map and since this is tagged as an Android question, you can also use string XML resoure files to represent this. You should be able to read this from any class with Context https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#String

Answer (score 14):

> As it's a static function i can't use any kind of global variable (like hashmap)

Sure you can.

```
private static final HashMap<String, String> LANGUAGES = new HashMap<>();

static {
  LANGUAGES.put("AD", "ca");
  // TODO: rest of mappings go here
}

private static String countryToLanguage(String countryCode){
  return LANGUAGES.get(countryCode);
}
```

Comment: Nit: as it is a global variable, make it immutable to avoid potential corruption. Either use an actually immutable map implementation (like Guava's ImmutableMap), or build a local `HashMap` in the initializer, and then assign `LANGUAGES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(localMap);` at the end.

Comment: And also Map interface should be used, like: private static final Map<String, String> LANGUAGES... otherwise you won't be able to assign it to unmodifiableMap.

Comment: I'm curious, is it a good idea to have so many values in a static variable? Since it would stay as long as the app is running.

Comment: hmmm but for broadcast receiver that are call in background when location changed, does the engine will not internally initialise every time a new LANGUAGES ?

Comment: @loki: That `static` block will only be executed once per process. If your process was terminated, and a new process is needed, everything will need to be loaded again. The disk I/O of loading your Java class (with either a really long method or a really long `static` block) should be far greater than the time it takes to initialize the `HashMap`. Plus, the `HashMap` lookup will be significantly faster than the one-at-a-time lookup that your are doing with your `if-else` structure.

Answer (score 2):

Use a string switch:

```
switch (countryCode) {
  case "AD": return "ca";
  case "AE": return "ar";
  case "AG": return "en";
  // etc.

  default:
    // Do something if not found,
    // e.g. throw IllegalArgumentException,
    // or return a default value.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Guava in your project you can do the following:

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> LANGUAGES = ImmutableMap
.of("a", "A", 
    "b", "B", 
    "c", "C");
```